# Can't invoke chaincode from SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I can invoke chaincode from my peer by the following command:

```
peer chaincode invoke -o coreOrderer.dip.com:7050 --tls --cafile /etc/hyperledger/tlsca.dip.com-cert.pem --tlsRootCertFiles /etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt -C dipchannel -n mycc --peerAddresses peer0.core.dip.com:7051 -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
```

And it works, I can see in the peer logs:

```
Entry chaincode: name:"mycc"
Exit chaincode: name:"mycc"  (2ms)
```

And I can see result of this invoke in my chaincode container.

But when I'm trying to invoke from my code by SDK

```
    req := channel.Request{
        ChaincodeID: "mycc",
        Fcn:         "query",
        Args:        [][]byte{[]byte("a")},
    }
    resp, err := client.Execute(req)
```

I have empty response, and in the peer log I see:

```
Entry chaincode: name:"cscc"
Exit chaincode: name:"cscc"  (1ms)

Entry chaincode: name:"lscc"
Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (1ms)
```

Why it is calling "cscc" and "lscc" chaincodes and doesn't call to "mycc" ?

Comment: I found there is warn from SDK: pgresolver.(*randomLBP).Choose -> WARN No available peer groups. To resolve it I've changed Execute to "resp, err := client.Execute(req, channel.WithTargetEndpoints("peer0.core.dip.com"))" and now it works. Not sure if it is a good solution, because random peer must be selected by SDK by itself, I believe

Answer (score 0):

check this below are System Chaincodes

**LSCC** Lifecycle system chaincode handles lifecycle requests described above. >>> **Chaincode lifecycle**

**CSCC** Configuration system chaincode handles channel configuration on the peer side. >>> **which helps regulate access control**

**QSCC** Query system chaincode provides ledger query APIs such as getting blocks and transactions.

**Note**: In particular, install, instantiate and upgrade do not apply to system chaincodes.

System chaincode is used in Hyperledger Fabric to implement a number of system behaviors so that they can be replaced or modified as appropriate by a system integrator.

Unlike a user chaincode, a system chaincode is not installed and instantiated using proposals from SDKs or CLI. It is registered and deployed by the peer at start-up

> > > > COMING to your query >>>>

Check whether you are providing identity or not, as it enters into CSCC which is a regulator for ACL

Check below my code snippet

```
func (setup *FabricSetup) Query() (string, error) {
    // Channel client is used to query and execute transactions
    clientContext := setup.sdk.ChannelContext(setup.ChannelID, fabsdk.WithUser(setup.OrgAdmin))
    client, err := channel.New(clientContext)
    setup.client = client
    // Prepare arguments
    var args []string
    args = append(args, "queryRate")
    args = append(args, "001")

    response, err := setup.client.Query(
        channel.Request{
            ChaincodeID: setup.ChainCodeID,
            Fcn:         args[0],
            Args:        [][]byte{[]byte(args[1])},
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to query: %v", err)
    }

    return string(response.Payload), nil
}
```